# Using "love" to address someone

Tags: грамматика

For example: 
Girlfriend: Hello, love! 
Boyfriend: Hello!

In English it doesn't change if you're talking to a guy or a girl, but I've noticed some words might change in Russian if you're talking to a guy or a girl.

Comment: I gotta warn you that this is not a translation service per se.

Answer (score 3):

English "love" can be used in a wider set of scenarios compared to the "любимый" mentioned in an answer provided. "Любимый" is for somebody very closely-related, a wife, a lover, a child may be, well, may be a woman can tell it to her close friend.

Russian word ["дорогой"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9) ("дорогая" in feminine) is the other word one might look for when trying to transmit English "love" in this context. It's more neutral yet applicable if one might want to express an extreme level of sympathy. See also [this](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/19736/why-do-russians-call-their-women-expensive-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%8F/19744) question answers to which give a nice summary of what else can be used, like `милый`(`милая` in feminine).

Answer (score 3):

'Love' is not necessarily about addressing a girlfriend. Here's about its British usage towards *strangers*:

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/199609/can-i-help-you-love-love-as-a-form-of-address-is-it-used-regionally-to-talk

As I can remember, in the famous 'Blowup' movie that form of address was used there towards a girl just working in the same photo studio (a co-worker). In Russian, such form might sound like something between *красавица* and (not as nice) *дорогуша*.

Answer (score 2):

In this context the word "love" could be translated as

> любимый (to a guy)
>   любимая (to a girl)

And "Hello, love!" to a guy is translated as

> Привет, любимый!

Comment: thank you for your help!

Comment: @Illiana And I have to warn you to be cautious when using the words in the answer - these Russian equivalents are way more intimate (when used to address someone) than the English 'love'...

Comment: FWIW, “*любовь моя*” is also acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Любимый sounds very intimate. It is better to use a neutral style - Милый, милая addressing somebody.

Answer (score -2):

To be exact, this is the meaning of "Моя любовь" (My Love), I think, it have very pathos, and it is an intimate.

It doesn't have declination on the gender to real addressee..